# How to retrieve version of a module on apache

Tags: apache, httpd.conf, docker-container, openid-connect, mod-auth-openidc

We run `httpd` in a docker container on *apache* web server. Is there a command or script or any way to directly retrieve `auth_openidc_module` version used there.
The module name is `mod_auth_openidc.so`.

Any help here will be greatly appreciated as always.

Comment: Try with `apachectl -M` it will show loaded modules might be possible it will show version.

Comment: that just displays the module names not the versions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may get you your answer:

```
 strings /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_auth_openidc.so | grep mod_auth_openidc
```

Comment: Of course, you'd have to be able to run that command within your docker instance.

Comment: Thanks Mark for the prompt response. I had tried that already in my docker container but then as expected it says strings command not found.

Comment: Ah i just i did  apt-get install binutils, then queried :- strings /usr/local/apache2/modules/mod_auth_openidc.so | grep mod_auth_openidc and that worked. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The module prints out its version number at startup. The `LogLevel` must be set to `info` or `auth_openidc:info` for that. E.g.:

`\$ cat /usr/local/logs/error_log | grep "mod_auth_openidc" | grep "init"
[Fri Jul 06 08:23:42.099952 2018] [auth_openidc:info] [pid 43686:tid 140735991522176] mod_auth_openidc-2.3.7 - init - cjose 0.5.1, OpenSSL 1.1.0e-dev, EC=yes, GCM=yes, Redis=yes, JQ=yes`